Central extensions versus 2-cycles
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $[C]\in H^2 (G;\mathbb{R})$. Then $\hat{G}_C :=G\times \mathbb{R}$ with multiplication $(g,r)\cdot (f,s):=(gf,r+s+C(g,f))$ (i.e. $\hat{G}_C=G\ltimes \mathbb{R}$) is a central extension of $G$. I know that $[C]=[C']$ iff central extensions $\hat{G}_C$ and $\hat{G}_{C'}$ are equivalent. My question is that if $\hat{G}$ is a central extension of $G$, then is there a 2-cocycle $C$ for which $\hat{G}=\hat{G}_C$?

You need for there to exist a smooth section (which will of course not be a homomorphism except in the trivial case) of the map $\widehat{G} \to G$. I am not sure if this is automatic or not. Pick such a section, and write it as $g \mapsto \widetilde{g}$.
Then for any $g, h \in G$, the element $\widetilde{g}\widetilde{h}(\widetilde{gh})^{-1}$ of $\widehat{G}$ maps to zero in $G$, so comes from an element $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{R}$. It is straightforward to check that the map $(g, h) \mapsto \alpha$ turns out to be a smooth 2-cocycle and that it only depends on the choice of smooth section up to a 2-coboundary.
